# How do I use Windows Authentication with RESTier 0.5.0

Tags: restier

For the purposes of custom authorization I need to find out who the current user is so I can determine if they are authorized.

Can I use the **[Authorize]** Attribute to force Windows Authentication?

Can I then use **Thread.CurrentPrincipal** to determine who the user is?